# Can't get result from sql using ajax result

Tags: ajax, wpdb, sql

I'm using an AJAX form to feed the code something to lookup in db. Separate table, not WP options.

I'm getting the result from AJAX, but when I try to do the sql it just returns 0.

This is the function:

```
   function myajax_inputtitleSubmit_func() {
    // check nonce
    $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];   
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    $zipcode = $_POST['zip'];
    // generate the response
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename  = "{$wpdb->prefix}levering";

    $sql    = "SELECT Levering FROM {$tablename} WHERE Zip LIKE %s";
    $result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $zipcode));
    return $result;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $response = $row['Levering'];
        }

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;
    die();
    // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
    exit;
}
```

Comment: A couple of questions - why there is a return statement?   You have used get_var() which returns a single variable as result, so why looping has been done?

Comment: It's from another attempt to solve the problem, has no meaning anymore - and has been deleted since this was posted with no change in result.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes to your code. See now if this works -

```
function myajax_inputtitleSubmit_func() {
    // check nonce
    $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];   
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    $zipcode = $_POST['zip'];
    // generate the response
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename  = "{$wpdb->prefix}levering";

    $sql    = "SELECT Levering FROM {$tablename} WHERE Zip LIKE %s";
    $result = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($sql, $zipcode));

    $response = array();

    foreach($result as $res){
        $response[] = $res;
    }
    // response output
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
    // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Turn out there was a couple of other mistakes, but your code did the trick.
Now I get the result ["Mandag, onsdag og fredag"] - how do I get this down to the raw string?

Comment: I managed to remove the [], now I just need to remove the qoutes.
But I also need to handle the situation where the sql call doesn't return an answer - how is this done?